# Reload when fetching new posts on Wordpress.com blog

Tags: wordpress.com

By default, Wordpress.com blogs enable infinite scrolling. However, syntax highlighting for embedded source code does not work for dynamically loaded content. I disabled infinite scrolling on my blog, so now there is an `Older Posts` button at the bottom of the page that loads more content. Unfortunately, this still uses AJAX to load the new content dynamically. The page is not reloaded, so the syntax highlighting still doesn't work for the dynamically loaded content.

Is there a way to enable post pagination or force WordPress.com to reload the page when new content is requested?